# Render Method, Meteor React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

After following the getting started tutorial on the meteor website i stopped around the item "2.4 Create App component", first install:

```
meteor add http
```

The app purpose is to visualize in differently the lottery api data of the state of New York.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';

var apiUrl = 'https://data.ny.gov/api/views/dg63-4siq/rows.json';

export default class App extends Component {

  numbers() {
    HTTP.get(apiUrl, {}, function(err, res){
        if(err){
            console.log('ERROR @ CALL');
        } else {
            console.log(res);
            return res.data.data.slice(-50).map((result, index) => 
            <li key={ result[0] }>{`${result[8]} - ${result[9]}`}</li>
            );
        }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Numbers</h1>
        </header>
        <ul>
          { this.numbers() }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the object from the http call shows up on the console but not on the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its a good idea to call the functions that makes an API call in the render function as it will be called everytime the component renders, a better place will be to have it in the componentDidMount function and save the result in state. If you want the call to repeat, do it in setInterval function like

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {data: []}
  componentDidMount() {
    var comp = [...this.state.comp]
    this.interval = setInterval(()=> {
      HTTP.get(apiUrl, {}, function(err, res){
        if(err){
            console.log('ERROR @ CALL');
        } else {
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({data: res.data.data.slice(-50)})

        }
        }.bind(this)); 
     }, 2000)

  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
       clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Numbers</h1>
        </header>
        <ul>
          {this.state.data.map((result, index) => 
             <li key={ result[0] }>{`${result[8]} - ${result[9]}`}</li>
            ); }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Final code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';

var apiUrl = 'https://data.ny.gov/api/views/dg63-4siq/rows.json';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = { data : [] }; 
  }
  componentDidMount(){
      var self = this;
          HTTP.get(apiUrl, {}, function(err, res){
              if(err){
                  console.log('ERROR @ CALL');
                  } else {
                      self.setState((state, props) => ({
                          data : res.data.data.slice(-50)
                          }));
                      console.log("state equals response");
                  }
          });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Numbers</h1>
        </header>
        <ul>
          {this.state.data.map((result) => 
             <li key={ result[0] }>{`${result[8]} - ${result[9].split(' ')}`}</li>
            )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```